# Adding links on each items for more information inside the php loop

Tags: php, html

[image: Linking Info on each]

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM adoption");

if($result->num_rows !=NULL){
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $AAnimalName = $rows['AAnimalName'];
        $Abreed = $rows['Abreed'];
        $Asex = $rows['Asex'];
        $Acolor = $rows['Acolor'];
        $image = $rows ['image'];
        $a_id = $rows['a_id'];
        $image_location = "admin/function/upload/".$image; ?>
        <div class="container-custom1">
        <?php
        if(file_exists($image_location )) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image_location.'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="admin/images/admin_logo.png" width="248" height="190" class="age1" title>'; } ?>

        <?php echo "<i><h1 class='junction'><a style='cursor:pointer' class='junction'>".$AAnimalName."</a></h1></i><button type='button'
 id='button2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#contact'
 data-original-title>Adopt</button></button>"."<br>".$Asex." /
 ".$Abreed."<br>".$Acolor."<br>"."ID#: ".$a_id;?></div>

        <?php
     } }   
?>
```

Here is my code to display each item. Should I add an HTML id tag to the database, or is there any way I can do it from another PHP page?

Comment: you want to go to new page when adopt is clicked?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have a modal for `Adopt` button. I want the name of the animal to go to new page for viewing more information about the animal. When the picture or name is clicked.

Comment: Add an `href` to the anchor so clicking on it will open the new page.

Comment: `echo "<a href=\"newpage.php?animal_ID=".$row['a_id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_location."\" width =\"248\" height=\"190\" class=\"age1\" title=\"\"><a/>";` Then on the newpage u will use $_GET to get the id of the animal once u get tht u display the info

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile is this only 1 page for all? Okay, i will create new page for that. I will update you.

Comment: @Powerballs yes its one page for all, the page will be dynamic, it will only pull results of the selected image id only, I hope ur a_id are unique?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile The code was awesome. Tried applying it and it works. So now, i have to create the `page.php` and `$_GET` each?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile a_id are unique.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Make your comment as an answer so i can upvote you bro.

Answer (score 2):

what you will need to to is to wrapper the image around with an anchor tag, then the anchor tag will link to the target page then add a query string within your anchor tag eg if we going to page.php u add a query string like page.php?ID=5 then on the page.php we will request the id from the query string then perform our necessary queries.

there add

```
echo "<a href=\"newpage.php?animal_ID=".$row['a_id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_location."\" width =\"248\" height=\"190\" class=\"age1\" title=\"\"><a/>";
```

Your full code will look like:

```
<?php
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM adoption");

 if($result->num_rows !=NULL){
     while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {

         $AAnimalName = $rows['AAnimalName'];
         $Abreed = $rows['Abreed'];
         $Asex = $rows['Asex'];
         $Acolor = $rows['Acolor'];
         $image = $rows ['image'];
         $a_id = $rows['a_id'];
         $image_location = "admin/function/upload/".$image; ?>
         <div class="container-custom1">
         <?php
         if(file_exists($image_location )) {
     echo "<a href=\"newpage.php?animal_ID=".$row['a_id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_location."\" width =\"248\" height=\"190\" class=\"age1\" title=\"\"><a/>";
         }
     else {
     echo '<a href="newpage.php?animal_ID='.$row['a_id'].'<img src="admin/images/admin_logo.png" width="248" height="190" class="age1" title></a>'; } ?>

         <?php echo "<i><h1 class='junction'><a style='cursor:pointer' class='junction'>".$AAnimalName."</a></h1></i><button type='button'
 id='button2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#contact'
 data-original-title>Adopt</button></button>"."<br>".$Asex." /
 ".$Abreed."<br>".$Acolor."<br>"."ID#: ".$a_id;?></div>

 <?php

     } }   

 ?>
```

then on newpage.php

Your will first check if the id isset if its set u request it and use the id to perform ur query

**Newpage.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['animal_ID'])){
    $aID = intval($_GET['animal_ID']);


    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoption where a_id = ?");
    $result->bind_param('i', $aID);
    $result->execute();

        // continue your query

}else{

    echo "animal id not set";
    //exit or redirect back
}

?>
```

> NB: If you not using prepared statements yet, you should consider
>   using them,

Comment: i echoed informations on //continue your query but only ID#9 is shown whenever i clicked any of this.

Comment: @Powerballs are you still struggling?